# Why won't my .Net Windows service start automatically after a reboot?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I get the error below in the event log when the computer boots, the service is set to automatically start, when I manually start the service it starts without a problem.

Any ideas?

Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010002): Call was canceled by the message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your service depend on some other component/service that may not have started up yet at machine boot?

Comment: Jonas is probably right, so to test it out, try putting in a Thread.Sleep call for a decent amount of time, during your start up event before any work begins.

Comment: Yeah, this is a decent suggestion.

Comment: We have this same problem at our company with a service depending on SQL to be started before our service is started...I think we have a timer that tries a configurable number of times before giving up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into what it could be.

Comment: You can make your service dependent on other services in configuration, and therefore no need to sleep an arbitrary amount of time - your service will simply not be started until its dependent services are running.

Comment: @Alan Right on; to find out what services your service depends on, if you are unsure, go to Administrative Tools - Services, bring up Properties on your service, and check the Dependencies tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding a dependency to the Windows Management Instrumentation service (winmgmt.exe).

Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454379/1003958