# Why does my .NET Windows service not start automatically sometimes?

Tags: .net, windows, service, system.management

I have modified a working Windows service that had always been starting beforehand. After adding the System.Management reference it now sometimes will not start automatically. I get the following error:

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80010002): Call was canceled by the
>   message filter. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010002
>   (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))

I found another post here on SO with someone having the same issue.

[Why won't my .Net Windows service start automatically after a reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998883/why-wont-my-net-windows-service-start-automatically-after-a-reboot)

However, the proposed solution was to have the service start after the services it depends on have started. However, when I go to the Dependencies tab for my service, I see:

[image]

Should I just use the workaround method of putting the thread to sleep, or is there a more proper way of getting this service to start correctly? Is this happening because .NET has not started before my service starts?

Thanks,

Tomek

EDIT: I have added a try-catch statement to catch the exception. Here is the code that I added to the OnStart() method of my service (which is where the exception is being thrown)

```
        try
        {
            _watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
            _watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
            _watcher.Start();  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Could not create Sleep/Resume watcher" + ex.Message);
        }
```

The service does start now but without the functionality that I have added. I am new to .NET, but I took the watcher code from a sample I found online, so I am pretty sure it is correct. The Event Log displays the same exception:

> Could not create Sleep/Resume watcher Call was canceled by the message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))

Comment: You might also try posting your question on ServerFault.com

Comment: Since you now use WMI, you should probably wait for the Windows Management Instrumentation Service to start. Try adding it to dependent services on install time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Thread.Sleep(10000) right before I create the ManagementEventWatcher (before the try statement)

It is kind of a workaround, but it did fix the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I've had this problem myself and apparently it only occurs on Windows XP (not on Vista or Win 7).
To fix this you need to add a dependency to the Windows Management Instrumentation service.
Adding this dependency to your existing service is done in three simple steps:

1. Open the command prompt (Windows+R -> cmd -> enter)
2. Type: sc config "NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE" depend= winmgmt
3. Press enter, you should see: [SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

Restart your computer and your service should now start correctly.

Comment: This is the correct answer! You can also add the dependency to the service installer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the service itself, it's that the new component you added a reference to is throwing an unhandled exception (Call was canceled by the message filter). Troubleshoot that error message with whatever code you added, and/or put in better error handling so that an error in that component will not bubble up to the top and cause the service to stop :-)

Comment: @Joel Martinez I have added the try-catch but am getting the same exception (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

If you depend on another service, us sc.exe to configure your service to start after the dependency. This cannot be done through the Services applet.

Comment: how can I find out which services my service depends on other than the Services applet?