# .net 5.0 windows service does not start automatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, .net-5

I have a .net 5.0 windows service defined as bellow

`.UseWindowsService();`

which is set to auto start delayed but it wont start automatically only manually so I know that there no issue with the service its self. the only thing I can think of is that
the service uses `System.IO.FileWatcher` and `System.IO.Pipes`. is that a  dependency that I need to say that the service depends on? if yes which one?

Comment: Do you have any sort of logging with your application? Have you inspected Event Viewer for issues?

Comment: Can you describe the steps you took to determine that it won't start automatically?

Comment: I have logging in my application but nothing is being logged neither in my log and the Event Viewer as well.

Comment: I restarted the computer (p.s. the pc is being logged in by auto logon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to configure the service to depend on `winmgmt` by opening the cmd prompt

`sc config "NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE" depend= winmgmt`
I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454379/2733492)